# Setting chromium-browser AppArmor profile to "enforce" makes Chromium crash

Tags: chromium, crash, apparmor

I have tried setting the AppArmor profile for Chromium to enforce mode, but whenever I launch Chromium it displays these messages and then crashes:

```
Using PPAPI flash.
[23426:23426:0106/190945.295059:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(199)] Check failed: ReceiveFixedMessage(fds[0], kZygoteBootMessage, sizeof(kZygoteBootMessage), &boot_pid). 
#0 0x7f465f584e9c <unknown>
#1 0x7f465f5a685e <unknown>
#2 0x7f465d08ac6b <unknown>
#3 0x7f465d0897c5 <unknown>
#4 0x7f465d089d71 <unknown>
#5 0x7f465cc3f7ac <unknown>
#6 0x7f465cc457ca <unknown>
#7 0x7f465cc3eee6 <unknown>
#8 0x7f465d54510b <unknown>
#9 0x7f465faa3dd7 <unknown>
#10 0x7f465d543f61 <unknown>
#11 0x56188cf29cec <unknown>
#12 0x7f4653283830 <unknown>
#13 0x56188cf29b49 <unknown>

Received signal 6
#0 0x7f465f584e9c <unknown>
#1 0x7f465f5849f1 <unknown>
#2 0x7f465f6e5390 <unknown>
#3 0x7f4653298428 <unknown>
#4 0x7f465329a02a <unknown>
#5 0x7f465f582715 <unknown>
#6 0x7f465f5a6b49 <unknown>
#7 0x7f465d08ac6b <unknown>
#8 0x7f465d0897c5 <unknown>
#9 0x7f465d089d71 <unknown>
#10 0x7f465cc3f7ac <unknown>
#11 0x7f465cc457ca <unknown>
#12 0x7f465cc3eee6 <unknown>
#13 0x7f465d54510b <unknown>
#14 0x7f465faa3dd7 <unknown>
#15 0x7f465d543f61 <unknown>
#16 0x56188cf29cec <unknown>
#17 0x7f4653283830 <unknown>
#18 0x56188cf29b49 <unknown>
  r8: ffff98f4847cc240  r9: ffff98f4847cc230 r10: 0000000000000008 r11: 0000000000000206
 r12: 00007f46539ad1c0 r13: 00007ffee33da9c0 r14: 00000000000000ac r15: 00007ffee33da9b8
  di: 0000000000005b82  si: 0000000000005b82  bp: 00007ffee33da410  bx: 00007ffee33da460
  dx: 0000000000000006  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 00007f4653298428  sp: 00007ffee33da2d8
  ip: 00007f4653298428 efl: 0000000000000206 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000000
 trp: 0000000000000000 msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000000
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
```

Does anyone know why this would be happening? I am using a custom build of Chromium with hardware acceleration enabled from here: https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-dev.

Comment: Did you check syslog to see what is being blocked which might cause it to abort? (It's not crashing, exactly, but seems to be aborting because it's unable to verify which OS you're on.)

Comment: Contact the maintainer or debug it. We can not tell from what little you posted